# How to unfreeze the size of palettes in the 12.0 version

Tags: palettes, version-12.0

I have a counter-natural question. It started from the move from version 12.2 to 12.0 which for whatever unnatural reason was forced by the university. The latter is subscribed for Mathematica and it is this university license that I use.

With this older version, I noticed that the sizes of all the palettes (e.g. Menu/Pallets/Special Characters or Menu/Pallets/Writing Assistant) are frozen down. That is, the palettes are about 1/3 smaller than it has been previously and I got used to. Only a part of the information can be visible, the other part is hidden. The slider to show it is only in the vertical, but not in the horizontal direction. Thus, there seems to be a part that cannot be visualized. "Seems to be" because I did not manage to get it visualized and, thus, I am not sure.

The worst of all is that they are frozen: I am unable to drag the corner of the palette to increase its size, or to increase it another way around.

Any idea of how to change that? Where in the OptionInspector does one find the corresponding settings?

The system is Win10

Comment: What operating system is this on?

Comment: @ 
Carl Lange It is Win. 10

Comment: I have seen this issue with my own palettes, but have not been able to reproduce in a consistent way to report it.

Answer (score 1):

The problems were seemingly related to the fact that I used files generated within Math. 12.2 after I passed to Math.12.0. As soon as I created a file in 12.0 from the very beginning the palettes took the expected appearance.

It is, evidently, the case that the problem was raised due to an error of working in an earlier version with a file generated in a later one.

I have to apologize for this question and vote to close it.

Comment: Do you have a method to fix this issue that you encountered? Or is it the case that you must transfer the code from the “broken” 12.2 files to that of a newly created file in the 12.0 version?

Comment: @ CA Trevillian What I did is the following: 1. I created the file in M12.0 2. Copy-pasted the content from the file created within the r version 12.2 into this new file. Done. The palettes work properly. However, I still have problems with the numeration of the formulas.